# App Submission procedure for specific/private purpose app

Tags: ios

I want to ask if i want to create an app for my college through which staff and students can review their attendance or marks. Simply it means my college specific app. So it should be available on app store or not? Or any other direct link procedure. Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's off-topic.

Comment: let me edit title sir

Comment: Has nothing to do with the title. There is no programming question here.

Comment: because there is no need of programming here.. This is post programming step after app building

Comment: it can get accepted. if it doesn't use testflight to send to the testers using their email

Comment: Thanks @Shubhank  Hope this should be appropriate answer for my question.

Comment: the question would be closed. the site expects decent questions/answers programming questions which this isnt. Try doing your own research for the matter

Comment: Tell me if there any procedure of getting apps directly somewhere from a link(e.g. My college website) but not available on app store. Just like in case of google play Store?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but about release requirements and procedures of a third party.

Comment: So where should I ask this query? @MarkRotteveel

Answer (score 1):

Apple has an enterprise developer program for this exact situation. See the following link [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html)

Comment: If I submit this specific app to app Store for review, Will Apple pass this app or not, for my case. Tell me please @deanware

Comment: There is no app submission to Apple for this enterprise app program. Your organization is responsible for hosting and providing a url to your users in order to install the app. Apple mentions the use of an MDM (mobile device management system) to help with the distribution.

Comment: But if I am the only developer with no organisation with no Enterprise program, and wants to submit this app on app store for testing/review. Will Apple pass it or reject? @deanware

Comment: There is no way to determine beforehand if Apple will accept or reject your app. If want you want to do is just create an app for your school and do not want to use the enterprise developer program, then you will have to create the app and submit to Apple for review just like everyone else.

Comment: Thankyou so very much for your suggestions Sir and sparing your precious time for my doubts

Comment: Your welcome. If you found the information I provided useful then please accept my answer.